# Does Rails have a way to reset class variables between requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, lifecycle, class-variables

I realized [when thinking about the user, password, and site variables in ActiveResource::Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088126/is-it-thread-safe-to-set-active-resource-http-authentication-on-a-per-user-basis), that they could be modified on one request and would remain modified on the next request. That seems like undesirable behavior, and possibly a widespread problem, since it applies to all use of class variables / attributes.

Does Rails provide a mechanism for cleaning up changes to class-level state (e.g. reset to default) so that each request starts in a pristine condition?

If not, would it be possible to add a way of initializing class variables which would get re-applied at the beginning of each request? This could be combined with thread-safe storage, making class variables much less problematic. A possible modification of [class_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/class_attribute)?

**Update:**

As I described in [the linked question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088126/is-it-thread-safe-to-set-active-resource-http-authentication-on-a-per-user-basis), the specific case that brought this to my attention was the fact that I was setting ActiveResource::Base.user and password on a per-user basis. If I ever failed to reset them, that would mean that REST requests on behalf of one user would be made using the credentials of another on subsequent page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, can you give a concrete example of why you want to do this? On the face of it, it sounds like you're requesting a change to a variable, so Rails is doing what you're asking for.

As far as an answer, a few options:

- There's no automatic "switch back to default" behavior for variables, no.
- You could manually reset the values at the end of each controller action where you want this to happen
- You could write a module that does this (called it, "acts_as_resettable"?), and then include that module in the classes where you want this functionality

Comment: It seems like extending class_attribute would be a good way to do this, because it already provides the behavior I want (inheritable class-level attributes). It could be passed a default value which it would save and reset on every request, and it could make use of Thread.current as @KandadaBoggu suggested in the other post in order to guarantee thread safety if that's an issue.