# Set site/user fields in ActiveResource

Tags: ruby, activeresource, highrise

I am building a sinatra app that will use Highrise CRM gem to access Highrise data. This gem is based on ActiveResource class. I want to set site, user fields for every request. I followed suggestion posted here - [Is it thread safe to set Active Resource HTTP authentication on a per-user basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088126/is-it-thread-safe-to-set-active-resource-http-authentication-on-a-per-user-basis). I add code (shown below) and I get an error. Can anyone help understand this error and how to fix it.

```
class ActiveResource::Base
  class << self
    %w(site user).each do |attr|               

      define_method(attr) do
        Thread.current["active_resource.#{attr}"]
      end

      define_method("#{attr}=", val) do
        Thread.current["active_resource.#{attr}"] = val
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And the error:

```
c:/dev/hgadget/application.rb:18:in `block in singletonclass':
undefined local variable or method `val' for #<Class:ActiveResource::Base> (NameError)
    from c:/dev/hgadget/application.rb:12:in `each'
    from c:/dev/hgadget/application.rb:12:in `singletonclass'
    from c:/dev/hgadget/application.rb:11:in `<class:Base>'
    from c:/dev/hgadget/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from application_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

------------------------update-----------------------------

I tried your suggestion, I now get this error.

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `path' for "https://test.abcd.com":String:
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeresource3.0.11/lib/active_resource/base.rb:562:in `prefix'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeresource3.0.11/lib/active_resource/base.rb:667:in `collection_path'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeresource3.0.11/lib/active_resource/base.rb:856:in `find_every' 
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeresource-3.0.11/lib/active_resource/base.rb:777:in `find' application.rb:78:in `block in <main>'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1212:in `call'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1212:in `block in compile!'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:772:in `[]'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:772:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:788:in `route_eval'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:772:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:821:in `block in process_route'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing a lot with setting `site` option dynamically during runtime and the only solution I have found which will not lead to race condition.

```rb
class Runner
  def self.new(site)
    Class.new(ActiveResource::Base) do
      self.site = site
      self.element_name = 'runner'

      # your methods here
    end.new
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm trying to set up a form for objects from this anonymous class, but anonymous classes are not working with ActiveModel, and nor with forms. I'm getting: `Class name cannot be blank. You need to supply a name argument when anonymous class given`. Did you found any workaround to this problem? thanks.

Comment: It's not my use case, I only use it from internal code to fetch and post custom data, I even do not follow REST specs, so I don't know how it will work in standart workflow. But I'm also not happy with this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

While defining method with `define_method` you can specify its arguments passing them as arguments to the block and not to `define_method` itself. So you can define setter method like that:

```
define_method("#{attr}=") do |val|
  Thread.current["active_resource.#{attr}"] = val
end
```

Comment: I tried what you said, I get an error - "NoMethodError - undefined method `path' for "https://abcd.test.com":String:"