# How to set user password dynamically for resource invocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

How to set user password dynamically for resource invocation. Person Resource could be invoked using John's password or Joe's password. How should I change this code, so that I can make this dynamic in nature.

```
class PersonResource < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://user:password@api.foo.com:3000/"
end
```

Comment: How are you using `PersonResource.site` in your code, can you show a snippet, so that a better way can be figure out?

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the `site` class declaration:

```
class PersonResource < ActiveResource::Base
end
```

And then set `site` to the correct URL right before you use it:

```
PersonResource.site = "http://user:password@api.foo.com:3000/"
PersonResource.find(1)
```

Keep in mind that this is not thread safe.  If you've enabled Rails threaded mode (via `config.threadsafe!`) then you could run into race conditions. If Rails is not in threaded mode then this approach is fine.

Comment: No the above cannot be deployed in production, would need  a more elegant solution.

Comment: Here's a threadsafe solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088126/is-it-thread-safe-to-set-active-resource-http-authentication-on-a-per-user-basis